# Google Structure Data Breadcrumb Markup

Tags: html, google-search-console, structured-data

I"m trying to implement a breadcrumb for Google Structure Data and the following is what I trying to build.

Home > Category > Page Name

The problem start when my manager suggest the syntax.

This is what I got suggested by my manager.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
  <a href="https://www.example.com" itemprop="url">
    <span itemprop="title">Home</span>
  </a> >
</div>  

<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
  <a href=" https://www.example.com/blog" itemprop="url">
    <span itemprop="title">Category</span>
  </a> >
</div>  

<div itemscope itemtype="http://data-vocabulary.org/Breadcrumb">
  <a href=" https://www.example.com/blog/can-work-pregnant/" itemprop="url">
    <span itemprop="title">Page Name</span></a>
</div>
```

This is what i think is correct.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BreadcrumbList">
  <span itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/">
        <span itemprop="name">Home</span></a>
        <meta itemprop="position" content="1" />
  </span>
  <span class="seperator">></span>
  <span itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/category">
      <span itemprop="name">Category</span></a>
      <meta itemprop="position" content="2" />
      </span>
      <span class="seperator">›</span>
    <span itemprop="itemListElement" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ListItem">
    <a itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemprop="item" href="https://example.com/category/page">
      <span itemprop="name">Page Name</span></a>
      <meta itemprop="position" content="3" />
  </span>
</div>
```

If you try both syntax, you can see the first one creates 3 separate breadcrumbs instead of one with full data in it.

But since this is what suggested by my manager, I do not want to refuse it unless I have the strong reason to do so.

So, what I want to know is the pros and cons of using the first syntax. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is correct. It produces one breadcrumb trail of 3 levels. Your manager is incorrect. Their way made 3 different "trails" of one level each only. It's not a trail if there is only one item.[image]